# Rendering GIF images causes extensive memory usage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to render a GIF image (selected from photo library, whose data type is `PHAsset`), I use the following code:

```
PHImageManager().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { (data, _, _, _) in
    if let imageData = data {
        imageView.image = UIImage.gif(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

Where `.gif` is an extension to `UIImage` I copied from [here](https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif), I believe many people use it.

The problem is, when I run the above code, the memory usage rises by about 20+MB, which is not outrageous, however, when I delete this selected GIF asset, the memory usage does not drop. And if I go ahead and select more GIF assets, for each one I select and run the above code, the memory usage rises by 20+MB. Now it's not acceptable anymore as the memory usage will just go up and never drop until the app crashes.

I understand why the memory usage goes up when I render a GIF image, I mean, the image data sits in the memory. What I don't know is how to I deallocate the chunk of memory when I wish to delete the GIF image?

**--------------UPDATE-----------------**

1. The `UIImageView` on "TestScreen" displays the thumbnail of the selected GIF image
2. When I press the GIF image, the app will open the image in full screen mode and if it's a GIF image, it'll play the animated image by running the above code
3. The memory goes up and never drops when I repeatedly open the GIF image in full screen

Comment: With your demo your question is perfectly fine, don't worry about it. It is clear what you are asking. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory leak may be in your own code rather than in the `.gif` extension. Maybe the view controller that displays the `.gif` does not deinitiazile when you close it. Wherever the leak is, here are two ways to find it:

**a)** A very simple approach is to add a `print` command to the de-/initialization of your objects. So you can see in the console when an object should be deinitialized and free up memory but in fact doesn't, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {

   init() { 
      print("init: \(self)")
   }

   deinit { 
      print("deinit: \(self)")
   }
}
```

**b)** A more insightful and convenient method is to use **Xcode Instruments**.

It is a much more powerful way of inspecting the memory management of your app than adding `print` commands. Also, once you have figured out how to use it, you will love it as it automates a lot of steps and eventually you will be able to check for memory leaks with just a few clicks.

Here you can find a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/166125/instruments-tutorial-swift-getting-started) on how to use Xcode Instruments.

If you post the code for the screen with the black background that opens and displays the GIF it may give a hint what the problem might be. In most cases it is something like a delegate that is not declared `weak` or another form of [circular strong reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).